# How to edit parents objects as a child?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two classes in my project.

User has a parent object .

````
class User(AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self",on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='child_sections', blank=True, null=True)


class Article(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articles')
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)```
````

Here a parent and the child itself can edit any objects

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ("id","author","caption","timestamp")


    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        if attrs.get('parent').id == self.context['request'].user.pk
            return attrs
        elif attrs.get('id') == self.context['request'].user.pk
            return attrs
        raise ValidationError('Unauthorized Request')
```

Here parent can edit its child's object and a user can edit its own object.

What I want to do is simple:

A child can also edit parents object. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `attrs.get('parent').id == self.context['request'].user.pk` looks quite strange, it means that the primary key of the user and the parent have to be the same, but that can just be a coincidence, and does not mean the person is the owner. This is also not something to check at the serializer side, but at by permission classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does this help you?

```
def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        user = self.context['request'].user
        article_author = attrs.get('author')

        if user == article_author or user == article_author.parent or user.parent == article_author:
            return attrs
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Unauthorized Request')
```